# Dotnet restore not working

Tags: nuget, windows-10, .net-core

- dotnet Version: 1.1.0 (global.json)
- NuGet Version : 4.4.1.4656
- VS2017 v15.5.2 (as Administrator)
- .NET Core 1.1
- [The solution I am trying to build](https://github.com/autofac/Examples)

**Update I:**
I just changed the project to run under target framework **.NET Core v2.0 & sdk version 2.1.3** and I only get these kind of errors:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   **Error   NU1202**    Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.1.0
>   is not compatible with netcoreapp2.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0).
>   Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.1.0 does not
>   support any target
>   frameworks.   AspNetCoreExample   C:\Users\Admin\Source\Repos\Examples\src\AspNetCoreExample\AspNetCoreExample.csproj 1

**Update II:**

While the following solves the current issue, i am not sure if it solves the root cause for this issue.

Delete the global nuget.config file `%AppData%/Nuget/Nuget.config`.

I fixed this issue by doing the following:
I migrated the project to .net core 2.0 and changed the global.json to point to sdk 2.1.3.
Removed all references in AspNetCoreExample manually and added the latest version for all of them.

---

**Issues with target framework 1.1**

**When doing a restore from the solution in VS 2017:**

[image]

**When doing the restore from cmd (dotnet restore)**
[image]

**Running dotnet restore in Package Manager Console**

[image]
[image]

> NuGet.targets(103,5): error : Access to the path 'System.Runtime.dll'
>   is denied

**.NET Core SDKs installed:**
[image]

**.NET Host**
[image]

Now when opening the solution I get:

[image]

Comment: does it work on the 2.1.3 SDK? (change global.json)

Comment: no, it is not. The project is a .NET Core 1.1 project

Comment: doesn't matter, the SDK is only tooling, it is backwards compatible. if you change/remove the global.json and re-open VS, it should load newer targets and may (?) work around a nuget issue

Comment: got to the project's properties, verify that its really targeting .Net Core 1.1. An accidental mouse scrolling could have changed that. The problem is probably with the WebApplicationCoreTest project

Comment: @MartinUllrich Not working:
From the PMC I get:

 error NU1202: Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.1.0 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1). Package Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.Physical 1.1.0 does not support any target frameworks. [C:\Users\Admin\Source\Repos\Examples\Examples.sln]

Comment: @user2033402: It is set correctly.

Comment: From the command line I get:

C:\Users\Admin\Source\Repos\Examples\Examples.sln.metaproj : error MSB4126: The specified solution configuration "Debug|X64" is invalid. Please specify a valid solution configuration using the Configuration and Platform properties (e.g. MSBuild.exe Solution.sln /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform="Any CPU") or leave those properties blank to use the default solution configuration. [C:\Users\Admin\Source\Repos\Examples\Examples.sln]

Answer (score 0):

Comparing the log entries you pasted to their AppVeyor build,

https://ci.appveyor.com/project/Autofac/examples

Your machine's NuGet configuration seems to be broken. Analyze that and fix the issues.

Comment: Like you discovered in Update II, deleting the broken global setting can help. If you do want the project to be working fine everywhere (even if the global might be broken), you can add a nuget.config in the solution folder, and force to override all critical settings (like sources and so on). Please refer to NuGet documentation to see the details.

Comment: The problem is, I did a couple of things and my fix is not really a solution, because I did a migration (netcoreapp2.0/SDK 2.1.3) to mitigate the issues.

Answer (score 0):

You should add this code to your .csproj file

```
<RuntimeFramework>2.0.3</RuntimeFramework>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: which section does that go in?

Comment: In what section of the config file? Also this is .net 6. Thank you!